# Calulo de portes e excendente

Tags: php

Boa tarde,

Estou a fazer uma função que me devolva o valor do porte a pagar, onde este é fornecido através de intervalos, ou seja:

Peso <= 1 Kg devolve 3,00
Peso <= 2 Kg devolve 4,00
Peso <= 3 Kg devolve 6,00 ...
Até ao Peso <= 30 Kg devolve 20,00 ...

Só que o meu problema é se o produto pesar por exemplo 31 kg este deveria pegar no porte de 30 kg + porte de 1 kg e somar os dois e por aí fora.

Outro exemplo o produto pesar 68.5, ou seja, devia ser 30 kg +30 kg+1 kg e somar os valores todos.

Mas não sei como fazer este algoritmo, conseguem ajudar-me? Obrigado

Comment: 1 vai ser 3,00, 2 vai ser 4,00, 3 vai ser 6,00. Do 4 ao 19 vai ser o que?

Comment: Não entendi o porque do -1, uma vez que o peso entre o 4 e o 30 pode ser qualquer valor. Mas já consegui fazer o algoritmo como pretendia.

Comment: não foi eu que dei o -1, eu so fiz a pergunta acima! Abs;

Answer (score 0):

Faz um while reduzindo o peso:

```
$peso = 31;
$valor = 0;
while($peso >= 0){   
  if( $peso - 30 >= 0 ){
    $peso -= 30;
    $valor += 20;
  }
  if( $peso - 3 >= 0 ){
    $peso -= 3;
    $valor += 6;
  }
  if( $peso - 2 >= 0 ){
    $peso -= 2;
    $valor += 4;
  }
  if( $peso - 1 >= 0 ){
    $peso -= 1; 
    $valor += 3;
  }
}
```

Comment: este codigo não se encontra a funcionar, mas obrigado pela tentativa

Comment: OK. Se eu tiver outra ideia, posto aqui :).

Answer (score 0):

Verifica se faz o que precisa.

```
$peso = 61;
$valor = 0;

while($peso != 0)
{  
 if( $peso >= 30)
{
    $peso -= 30;
    $valor += 20;
}
else if( $peso >= 3){
    $peso -= 1; 
    $valor += 6;
}
else if( $peso >= 2){
    $peso -= 1; 
    $valor += 4;
}
else if( $peso >= 1){
    $peso -= 1; 
    $valor += 3;
}

}
```

Espero ter ajudado.